# GoogleMapsAPI - criar filtro de markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockoutjs

Estou a fazer um mapa dinâmico, usando a API do Google Maps que usa os markers para sinalar uma lista de localizações pré-definidas, tal como:

```
 self.locations = [{
        name: 'Foxtrot',
        lat: 38.713905,
        lng: -9.1518868,
        type: 'Bar'
     }
```

Tem também um campo Search que permite filtrar pelo nome das localizações (filteredNav). Também deveria filtrar os markers, mas não consigo. A recomendação que eu tenho é a seguinte:

> Try writing console.log(self.location_array());.Because location and
>   marker data modal is separate, you'll have to loop through
>   self.location_array() to process and find which one to show, which one
>   to hide by calling setVisible (or setMap) on the marker object.

```
// Create observable array
self.nav = ko.observableArray(self.locations);
// Create empty observable string
self.filter = ko.observable(''); 
// Show nav and filter
self.filteredNav = ko.computed(function() {

    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();

    if (!filter) {
        return self.nav();
    }
    return self.nav().filter(function(i) {
        // Check for proper casing or lowercase
        return i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || i.name.indexOf(filter) > -1;
    });

    //problema neste loop! Não sei como o fazer
    for (var i = 0; i < location_array()[i].length; i++) {
    //??????
        location_array()[i].setVisible(true);
    }//?????


 }
```

nota: implementação do *observable array*: `vm.location_array()[i]`

[Link para o mapa](http://inesarmadabras.github.io/Neighborhood-Map-Project/)
Como faço o loop?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi, falta você filtrar os marcadores, vc deveria guardar eles em um array e depois remover os que não estão na lista.

`var markers = [];
 var m = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: {lat: latitude, lng: .longitude},
   map: $scope.map,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
markers.push(m)`

Assim você consegue controlar a exibição deles removendo ou adicionando quando necessário.